# dojo chart height and width issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

This is my javascript code for dojo chart,whenever i am creating this chart in separate HTML page it is working fine, but when i am merging the same piece of code in my project then its svg taking **width:400px and height:300px**,but i have given div **width:200px and height:100px** this thing creating issue in my project,i am not been able to change its value,
please help me, thanks in advance.

```
"dojox/charting/plot2d/Columns",
"dojox/charting/Chart",       
"dojox/charting/themes/MiamiNice",
"dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",    
"dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",  

  var chart = new Chart("chartNode");
  chart.addPlot("default", {type: Columns, enableCache: true,gap:10});
  chart.addSeries("Series A", [50, 20, 30, 40, 10]);
  chart.setTheme(theme);
  chart.render();
```

This is html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like when you create the chart the node into which you place it is not yet added/displayed in your application. For this reason the chart takes it default size because he can't compute it (default size is 400/300). A solution is to make sure to add the chart node is displayed at initialization. The other solution is to later resize the chart calling chart.resize(width, height);